# How to setup a hibernate hbm xml identity generator for DB2 "GENERATED BY DEFAULT WITH SPECIFIER"

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, hbmxml

I got a hbm mapping for a column, that is set to identity generator

```
<class name="com.dummy.TestADTO" table="table_a">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="ID">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
...
</class>
```

and half of it already works together with my db2 key table column which is defined

```
ID NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, NO CACHE)
```

my dto is like the following:

```
package com.dummy;

    class TestADTO {

        private Integer id;

        public Integer getId(){ return id; }
        public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
    }
```

1. 'half of it' means, that I can set a null value for the id property and the ID column is set by the generator when hibernate session.merge(testadto) is called:

`insert into test_a(id) values (default);`

2. The other half which does not work is, that I can set a value for TestADTO.id=155, but the value is not used when hibernate inserts to db with session.merge(testadto). Instead the next value from the identity generator is used:

what I wanted was:

`insert into test_a(id) values (?);`
(where ? will be replaced by 155)

what I get:

`insert into test_a(id) values (default);`

How can I get that to work?